# I want to create a dynamic label with values from a database

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to create a dynamic label with values from a database.

I have tried the code below, but it didn't work for me.

```
public void Change  (KeyEvent event) throws IOException {

    String q="select * from Normal_report";
    try {
        pst=con.prepareStatement(q);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                Label ab=new Label();
                Button btn=new Button();
                vbox.getChildren().add(ab) ;
                vbox.getChildren().add(btn) ;   
            }
            ab.setText(rs.getString("test_id"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish but you should fix this:

```
        while(rs.next()){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Label ab=new Label();
            Button btn=new Button();
            vbox.getChildren().add(ab) ;
            vbox.getChildren().add(btn) ;   
        }
        -> ab.setText(rs.getString("test_id")); //move inside loop or keep reference outside
```

As the label ab can't be reached outside the loop.